# MVC 4 Web API Action return: Types vs HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action

What is the difference returning Types e.g.

```
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyType> Get()...
```

vs

Returning HttpResponseMessage:

```
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()...
```

??

Does MVC wraps types into HttpResponseMessage content object anyways? The result on the page looks the same besides when formatters are explicitly added.

What is the difference to the client?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference.

If you return CLR type, it will be wrapped with `HttpResponseMessage` anyway.

The only difference is that if you return `HttpResponseMessage` you get a chance to work directly with HTTP - so you can set headers, bypass `MediaTypeFormatters` and so on.

It's all a matter of personal preference and/or the activity that's performed in your action.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of figured that out. Returning `HttpResponseMessage` gives more flexibility with all kinds of services that might be included in the response.

Comment: Actually there is a small difference if you are using new help page generator functionality. In case of HttpResponseMessage it will not be able to determine return type thus it will not generate sample data. At least this is true with "ASP.NET Fall 2012 Update BUILD Preview"

Comment: @mdonatas HttpResponseMessage seems to do a really good job of subverting the power of the help generator. There used to be a HttpResponseMessage<T> generic, but for "type safety" reasons, it was removed - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/355170

Comment: I find it  more cumbersome to write unit tests when having to deal with HttpResponseMessage instead of a CLR type as well, but also prefer HttpResponseMessage over CLR type due to the added control

Comment: @mdonatas Old question I know, but it's possible to specify the specific response type for use in the help pages when using `HttpResponseMessage`, by using the `ResponseType` attribute on your actions: `[ResponseType(typeof(MyResponseType))]`