# .NET Web API HttpResponseMessage Pattern?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

So I've seen the Web API 2 Controllers return `HttpResponse` and the actual object.  Example:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        var app = apps.Single(c => c.Id == id);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<object>(app,
                Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
        };
    }
```

or

```
 public Application Get(string id)
    {
        return apps.Single(c => c.Id == id);
    }
```

My question which is the 'right' way?  #2 is much shorter but is it better to do #1 or does #2 do #1 automatically ... ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633174/mvc-4-web-api-action-return-types-vs-httpresponsemessage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910867/asp-net-webapi-controller-return-typed-entity-or-httpresponsemessage) SO questions.

The response will be the same (`HttpResponseMessage`) in both cases.

`HttpResponseMessage` allows you to work with HTTP protocol (e.g., via `Headers` property) and unifies your return type.

Returning CLR types can be more readable, but you loose flexibility to return different types with different status codes unless you use `dynamic` or `object` which defeats the purpose of returning a specific type.

Personally, I prefer to use `IHttpActionResult` (added in v2) and to specify a `ResponseTypeAttribute` on controller actions for the expected return type to improve readability.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Portfolio))]
public IHttpActionResult GetPortfolio([FromUri] long id)
{
    // get portfolio

    return Ok(portfolio);
}
```

You can easily manipulate response messages (in a RESTful way) using default `IHttpActionResult` implementations (see `OkResult` above). Avoiding constructing `HttpResponseMessage` yourself also keeps code clean. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) is an official article on `IHttpActionResult` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage) is an interesting SO conversation on `HttpResponseMessage` vs `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: Arguably, you don't WANT to allow the flexibility of returning different types; that just obfuscates the intent of the service and makes it less self-documenting. IMO, less code is better given two methods resulting in the exact same output. Plus, you could always switch to returning HttpResponseMessage if and when you NEED to work with the HTTP protocol. Otherwise, the HttpResponseMessage approach just adds clutter.

Comment: Self-documenting API arguments makes sense, but you can use `[ResponseType]` attribute to signal API response type to external docs like Swagger. I, personally, like the fluency of `return BadRequest()` compared to `Request.CreateErrorResponse`. Also, `IHttpActionResult` implementation can do more than just returning a value (e.g. add headers, log messages, etc.)